# Post process query results in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter I am looking for a way to do some post processing on queries on a specific table/model. I can think of a number of ways of doing this, but I can't figure out any particularly nice way that would work well in the long run.

So what I am trying to do is something like this:

I have a table with an serial number column which is stored as an int (so it can be used as AI and PK, which might or might not be a great idea, but that's how it is right now anyway). In all circumstances where this serial number is used (in views, search queries, real world etc.) it is used with an three letter prefix. So I can add this in the view or wherever needed, but I guess my question is more on what would be the best design choice. Is there a good way to add a column ('ABC' + serial) after queries so that it is mostly transparent to the rest of the application? Perhaps something similar to CakePHPs afterFind() hook?

Comment: create your own function to separate the id and prefix characters. There is no option in codeigniter like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in the query itself:

```
SELECT CONCAT(prefix, serial_number) AS prefixed FROM table_name
```

Comment: Ok, I guess this is the best option. I'll probably try to do as many of the queries as possible through the model so I only need to keep this in one place.